# Comparing multiple values to None

Tags: python, compare, interpreter, nonetype

How does the next piece of code work?

```
a = None
b = None
print(a == b) # True
print(a == b is None) # also True
```

The first print is pretty obvious, `None == None`, however, it is the second print which I do not understand. I can think of 2 ways to interprete this:

1. `(a == b) is None`, but this should (and does) give us False, since True is not None
2. `a == (b is None)`, this is also False since `b is None` is True and `None != True`

So, there is no way I can think of how Python gets `True` on this statement.

Comment: Comparisons chain in Python. `a==b is None` means `(a==b) and (b is None)` https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons

Answer (score 1):

Comparisons chain in Python.

`a==b is None` means `(a==b) and (b is None)`

See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons